# Imperative constructions in the passive voice

Tags: passive-voice, imperatives

There are certain uses of the Imperative that are in Passive voice. But the only examples I can think of are vulgar.

The obvious one is "Get f***ed!" Then there's "Get stuffed", "Get lost" etc.

I'm taking 'get' here as part of a passive construction. After all, "I got beaten" is essentially the same as "I was beaten."

And I can't see that 'beaten' can be taken as a PA because we can say "I got beaten by him."

I'm thinking these work as vulgar forms because you're not even telling someone to do something positive, you're telling them to submit to something.

I'm wondering if there are any Imperative constructions in the passive voice that aren't vulgar.

Comment: *Don't be intimidated by the Establishment! Vote Brexit!* To my mind, *to be intimidated* is at least as "passive" as *to get/be fucked*, and the fact that it's in a negated construction is by the bye.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. "Be intimidated by" is definitely passive. Perhaps the main issue is that in the passive, the subject (the implied 'you') is not the agent, and so cannot initiate an action. Whereas in the negated passive, you are urging them to exert agency. In the vulgar, you're just expressing a wish or desire or attitude.

Comment: *Be taught by the best! Sign up with [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)*

Comment: 'Be gone!' was a common one.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there are any Imperative constructions in the passive voice that aren't vulgar.

Yes. As one obvious example:

> Get checked out by a doctor as soon as possible.